# ¿Cómo extraer un dato concreto dentro de un .txt basado en líneas de Json?

Tags: python, json, diccionarios, txt

Me gustaría extraer dentro del archivo.txt solo los tweets que vienen con la clave 'text'. Esta es la primera linea del archivo .txt:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":294512601600258048,"id_str":"294512601600258048","user_id":90681582,"user_id_str":"90681582"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494083"}}
{"created_at":"Wed Sep 10 17:01:33 +0000 2014","id":509748524897292288,"id_str":"509748524897292288","text":"@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":509748106015948800,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"509748106015948800","in_reply_to_user_id":242563886,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"242563886","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Brenamae_","user":{"id":175160659,"id_str":"175160659","name":"Butterfly","screen_name":"VanessaLilyWan","location":"Canada, Montreal","url":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/vanessalilywan","description":"British youtubers. 'Nuff said.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":118,"friends_count":180,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":319,"statuses_count":10221,"created_at":"Thu Aug 05 20:03:16 +0000 2010","utc_offset":-36000,"time_zone":"Hawaii","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"B2DFDA","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"93A644","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"FFFFFF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/175160659\/1404361640","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Brenamae_","name":"I-G-G-Bye","id":242563886,"id_str":"242563886","indices":[0,10]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1410368493668"}
```

Mi código es:

```
tweets= open ('Tweets.txt')
contenido={}
for line in tweets:
    contenido=json.loads(line)
    print(contenido)
```

Con éste código no consigo acceder a la clave 'text' para extraer solamente los tweets. Cuando llamo a la variable contenido me muestra solamente esto:

```
{'delete': {'status': {'id': 509674096981192704,
   'id_str': '509674096981192704',
   'user_id': 2582708445,
   'user_id_str': '2582708445'},
  'timestamp_ms': '1410368500880'}}
```

Comment: Muestrra un segmento relevante de "tweets.txt"

Comment: exacto, iría bien un [mcve]

Comment: La pregunta es prácticamente igual a esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/371691/7123 Mira a ver si te sirve la respuesta que allí se da, y si no amplía tu pregunta explicando por qué no te sirve.

Comment: Acabo de agregar más información sobre el archivo .txt por si fuera de más ayuda. Muchas gracias!

Comment: no es recomendable poner enlaces externos, sino poner todo lo necesario en la pregunta. Utilizando el bloque de código puede añadirse mucho contenido de forma fácil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo que adjuntas tiene un diccionario por linea en formato json.

Por tanto, `contenido` es un diccionario y el item que busca es `diccionario['text']`. Ojo, no todas las lineas traen 'text'.

El código es:

```
import json

tweets = open ('Tweets.txt')
found = 0
linea = 0
for line in tweets:
    contenido=json.loads(line)
    linea += 1
    if 'text' in contenido:   
        found += 1
        print("%3d %4d text=%s" % (found, linea, contenido['text']))
```

que produce (numero, linea, texto):

```
  1    2 text=@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE
  2   15 text=Metin Şentürk Twitterda @metinsenturk MUHTEŞEM ÜÇLÜ; SEN, BEN, MÜZİK
  3   16 text=RT @byunghns:  I LOVE #틴탑 SO MUCH #쉽지않아 IS GOING TO BE SO GOOD 
  4   17 text=que hdp maicon lo que le hizo a david luiz jajajajajajajajajajaj,igual se jodio la carrera
  5   18 text=ドライ！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！
  6   19 text=RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
  7   20 text=RT @GossipRoomOff: Si Nathalie sait pertinemment que son couple ne va pas durer, alors pourquoi accepter
 la demande en mariage de Vivian ? …
  8   21 text=RT @Dayannalozano_: Junior va perdiendo... http://t.co/5mOsR7boLx
  9   22 text=RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
 10   23 text=RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
 11   24 text=الله أكبر الله أكبر الله أكبر, لا إله إلا الله, الله أكبر الله اكبر ولله الحمد http://t.co/M454OhQpYY
 12   25 text=TWİTTER'I AKRABALAR KEŞFEDİCEK DİYE ÇOK KORKUYORUM 
 Metin Şentürk Twitterda @metinsenturk
 13   26 text=RT @PINKBATHARRY: les saintes nitouches de ma classe qui aiment les 5sos si je leur montre le vine de la
 bite a calum on verra si elles son…
 14   27 text=RT @le_Parisien: Ebola : des pilotes d'Air France refusent les vols vers les pays touchés http://t.co/lt
37QKDwr2
 15   28 text=@hailee_danielsx I'm not mean cuz I'm ugly so ya
 16   29 text=You better believe your beautiful
 17   30 text=RT @baileymac02: CAN'T WAIT! I am playing @SoccerSix at The London Soccerdome on SUNDAY 26TH OCTOBER! Ti
ckets selling fast: http://t.co/c6i…
```

Parece estar bien ...

**Edición**

Cometi un error al contar las líneas. Lo corregi y ahora el listado refleja correctamente la línea donde se encontro `text`.

Comment: @JorgeMartín. Eso amerita una nueva pregunta. Redactala, agrega tu código, una muestra de datos de entrada y otra muestra con la salida que buscas.

Comment: Vale perfect muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: No consigo que se queden guardados en una variable fuera del bucle de tal forma que pueda utilizarla fuera de ese bucle. Añadí contenido_f=contenido['text'] pero solo me guarda el último tweet de la iteración
import json

tweets = open ('Tweets.txt')
found = 0
linea = 0
contenido_f={}
for line in tweets:
    contenido=json.loads(line)
    if 'text' in contenido:   
        found += 1
        linea += 1
        contenido_f=contenido['text']
        
print(contenido_f)

Comment: @JorgeMartín. Plantea una nueva pregunta para una nueva respuesta. Y aclara que quieres hacer con el texto del tweet. Eso es relevante para una respuesta adecuada. Espero